# way to pass variable through url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, get, pagination

I got a big search module in my Codeigniter project. Well simply I am passing variable to a view like

```
<a href=<?php echo site_url('controller/view/1');  ?>>View List</a>
```

And fetching its data in controller like

```
$id=$this->uri->segment(3);
```

For pagination

```
http://wwww.site.com/controller/view/<filter id>/<page from>
```

This is working perfectly in the case of simple query.

Now I got some more filter quires like

1. Country
2. State
3. City
4. Customer type
   etc etc

then the url should be

```
http://wwww.site.com/controller/view/1/id2/id3/i4/id5
```

Is this the correct way to do the process ? If not please give a little advice...
I am new to codeigniter

Comment: is it just a <a> link or your are using a form ??

Comment: have you tried to use form instead ?

Comment: bipen ... from the pagination link

Comment: @Ahmed Samy .. No .. Can you please give a link with form and pagination in codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing i have recently found a solution for this.

When you are first sending parameters through url use POST instead.
When you get the parameters you can pass them to session in a variable
type. Next time when you paginate get the type value from session and 
put it in your query to get the desired result.
If you have more than 1 parameters you can put them in sessions and 
unset them on certain conditions so that they are not called in every query.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here is to create another method in the controller something like filtered_view that accepts a filter_id and a page number, and that methode will fetch the data from the database with the provided filter and you'll use your pagination class as usual.
Hope this help.